# Duplicate/Delete in a custom module in Odoo 10/OpenERP

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

I'm trying to add a duplicate/delete in my custom module in odoo 10/openERP.

I have this in my model:

```
@api.multi
def copy(self, default=None):
    return super(Collection, self).copy()

@api.multi
def unlink(self):
    return super(Collection, self).unlink()
```

And this in my template/view:

```xml
<div class="o_kanban_manage_button_section">
    <a class="o_kanban_manage_toggle_button dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">More <i class="fa fa-caret-down"/></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>
            <a type="object" name="copy">
                <span>Duplicate</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a type="object" name="unlink" confirm="Are you sure you want to do delete this collection?">
                <span>Delete</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

They both work, but the confirm for the delete won't appear and the issue with the duplicate is that the page won't update, so the duplicate is only shown once you refresh the page.

I tried to return a reload for the copy function by doing this:

```
@api.multi
def copy(self, default=None):
    res = super(Collection, self).copy()
    return {
        'type': 'ur.actions.act_window',
        'tag': 'reload',
    }
```

But it gives out an error: `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'id'`

**EDIT 1**

I figured out that you can just use a widget to create a delete field.

```xml
<t t-if="widget.deletable"><li><a type="delete">Delete</a></li></t>
```

Comment: By default, the `Delete` and `Duplicate` actions should be on the `Action` dropdown on all the views you have defined for your model. Why do you try to add them this way?

Comment: @GeorgeDaramouskas It looks like it is so that they can Duplicate/Delete on a Kanban card.

Comment: @GeorgeDaramouskas what travisw said... I read from their forums that odoo won't allow you to reload a page right after creating a record, the reason being "you just can't" (the person answering's words, not mine... I can't produce the link though)... so I gave up on doing that...

Comment: @GeorgeDaramouskas I have created a new model in custom module but I can't see Delete in actions even though I am Administrator. Please assist